# How to Refactor this type of switch-case statement?

Tags: java, refactoring

Based on the minIndex, I am setting the different view visibility. I think it can be refactored as simple way.

```
switch (minIndex) {
    case 0:
        viewOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 1:
        viewTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 2:
        viewThree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 3:
        viewFour.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 4:
        viewFive.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
    case 5:
        viewSix.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
}
```

How can I refactor this code as a more readable code?

Comment: Not sure how practical this is but change all the references of your views into an array. Then use view[minIndex] to reference them.

Comment: Although I agree with Sotirios's Answer, but that goes on an assumption. YOur current code gives you an exact logic. The size of code hardly matters if your logic is intact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the numbers match up nicely with the actual view, you can use an array.

```
View[] views = new View[] {viewOne, viewTwo, viewThree, ...};
...
views[minIndex].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Very nice. Your solution is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've anonymized your code for this site. I was going to suggest what @Sotirios Delimanolis answered, but I think you are actually doing both too much and too little.

You've bound the controller too much to the view, and you've bound the views too much to each other.  Why should all of them be in the same `switch` statement?

How much will you need to change if you add another view?

Instead, you should have each view register a `PropertyChangeListener` with the object that holds `minindex`.  That's a bad name, by the way.  When the object changes `minindex`, it should send a `PropertyChangeEvent` to all the listeners.  Each view's listener should check whether the event wants that view to become visible; if so, the view should awaken itself.

```
class ViewController {
    private PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport();

    // delegate methods to add and remove listeners to pcs variable.

    private int viewIndex; // Changed for documentation.  Use String instead?

    public void setViewIndex(final int viewIndex) {
        int oldIndex = this.viewIndex;
        this.viewIndex = viewIndex; 
        pcs.firePropertyChange("viewIndex", oldIndex, this.viewIndex);
    }
}

class ViewOne {
    private ViewController vc;
    private final Integer myIndex = 1;

    // Constructor

    public void init() {
        // Never add this or an inner class to another object in a constructor.
        vc.addPropertyChangeListener("viewIndex",
            new PropertyChangeListener() {
                public propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if (myIndex.equals(evt.getNewValue()) {
                         setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

The warning about constructors is that if you expose `this` or an inner class of `this` to another object in the constructor, that external object may interact with `this` before it is fully constructed.  You can build the PCL in the constructor; use another method to add it to the controller.